# MYSQL update clause comparing the WHERE from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

```
$produpd = "UPDATE tblnavpc SET tblnavpc.ChildName = tblnav.NavName " .
    "FROM tblnav WHERE tblnavpc.CID = tblnav.NavID";
```

This is the error I get"

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'FROM tblnav
>   WHERE tblnavpc.CID = tblnav.NavID' at
>   line 1

I know keys aren't named greatly but I just trying to fix this one problem, I didn't name the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a FROM clause in an update:

```
UPDATE tblnavpc
INNER JOIN tblnav ON tblnavpc.CID = tblnav.NavID
SET tblnavpc.ChildName = tblnav.NavName
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave you credit cuz I tried yours solution first. I didn't think i could use a FROM clause either but I started trying anything I could think of besides INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

"From" cannot be used with update statements.
Should be

```
$produpd = "UPDATE tblnavpc SET tblnavpc.ChildName = tblnav.NavName " .
    "WHERE tblnavpc.CID = tblnav.NavID";
```

Comment: Where does this select the table tblnav ?